# How to solve this *without* handshake theorem?

Tags: combinatorics, alternative-proof

> Suppose $45$ handshakes occurred in a room, how many people were in the room?

Someone asked me this question and I was going to answer him using graph theory and my knowledge of the number of vertices in a  completed graph. But then he told me this is for a statistics class and I can't use any of those. I don't work with discrete math a lot, so the answer did not come to me immediately. Can someone show me a fundamental way or perhaps clever way to solve this by **not** brutally counting?

Comment: The question does not uniquely determine a solution. Do you additionally get to assume that every person shakes every other person's hand?

Comment: So you are solving $\binom{n}{2}=45$, that is $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}=45$. Simplify, you get a quadratic equation.

Comment: @James, yes that correct.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, I am an idiot….

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume there are $n$ people in the room, and no pair shook hands more than once.  If everybody shook hands with everybody else, there would be ${n \choose 2} = n(n-1)/2$ handshakes.  This is $45$ for $n = 10$, and less than $45$ if $n < 10$.  So there are at least $10$ people in the room.

Comment: I am an idiot, thanks…I couldn't even read my own thoughts.